# All .txt files are not being read after converting my java program into an executable file

Tags: java, executable-format

My java program contains two operations that uses data's stored in two different .txt files. It works completely fine when running using Netbeans but ones I make it into an executable file, the values from text files are not being read. What should do?

Comment: have you set your classpath right?

Comment: This sounds to me like an issue with having different System user.dir properties in Netbeans versus your executable. You are using relative (vs absolute) references to these files, correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. What do you mean by classpath?

Comment: how do u run your executable java file? is it? java -classpath path_to_txt_file ClassName

Comment: I used inno setup and packaged it as image in package as option found in netbeans, So, I basically got an exe file inside the project folder and I just open that.

Comment: Can you show us your code? That will make helping you a lot easier

Comment: Its quite huge actually, I cant paste them here. Also different operations belong to different frames. It was a software thing which reads value from txt file and store it back before closing the software.

Comment: @Amrutha.Sujith was your file in your source folder, or in a different location, like your desktop? Try putting the file in your desktop, and change the file name to `/Users/(yourName)/Desktop/(filename.extension)`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem are the paths of your .txt files in your code. Try using a absolute path instead of a relative path to ensure that the files can be found by your program, for example put the file in your desktop, then change the file name to `/Users/(name)/Desktop/file.txt`

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I said in my comment